# Active Director Ldap connection using Spring security

Tags: spring, spring-security, ldap

i am getting this error while trying to authenticate username and password against windows Active directory using
ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider class. If anybody has any idea please share it ........

**Versions**

3.2.0.RELEASE
4.0.1.RELEASE

### **Error**:

```
14:40:35,786 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-6) UT005023: Exception handling request to /eFin_iAnalytics/j_spring_security_check: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.replaceEach(Lj ava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
at org.springframework.ldap.core.DistinguishedName.un mangleCompositeName(DistinguishedName.java:250) [spring-ldap-core-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.ldap.core.DistinguishedName.pa rse(DistinguishedName.java:217) [spring-ldap-core-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.ldap.core.DistinguishedName.<i nit>(DistinguishedName.java:176) [spring-ldap-core-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.ldap.SpringSecurityLd apTemplate.searchForSingleEntryInternal(SpringSecu rityLdapTemplate.java:208) [spring-security-ldap-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.a d.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.search ForUser(ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider. java:285) [spring-security-ldap-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.a d.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.doAuth entication(ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvid er.java:130) [spring-security-ldap-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.A bstractLdapAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(Abs tractLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:61) [spring-security-ldap-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.authentication.Provid erManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156) [spring-security-core-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.authentication.Provid erManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:177) [spring-security-core-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.Us ernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthenti cation(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:9 4) [spring-security-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.Ab stractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(Abst ractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:211) [spring-security-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$ VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java: 342) [spring-security-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.a sync.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInte rnal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50) [spring-security-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilte r.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108) [spring-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$ VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java: 342) [spring-security-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityC ontextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPe rsistenceFilter.java:87) [spring-security-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$ VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java: 342) [spring-security-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy. doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192) [spring-security-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy. doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160) [spring-security-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterPro xy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344) [spring-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterPro xy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261) [spring-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(Ma nagedFilter.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterC hainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at com.adv.efin.ianalytics.webapp.filter.MDCFilter.do Filter(MDCFilter.java:77) [classes:]
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(Ma nagedFilter.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterC hainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleR equest(FilterHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecur ityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHa ndler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHan dler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java: 36) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityCo ntextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityCont extAssociationHandler.java:78)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handl eRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformati onAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationA ssociationHandler.java:113) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationCallHa ndler.handleRequest(AuthenticationCallHandler.java :52) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidential ityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHa ndler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfi dentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletC onfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthen ticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenti catedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandl er.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handl eRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCC ontextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler .java:61)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handl eRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handl eRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler .handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:240 ) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler .dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:227) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler .access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:73) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler $1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:146) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(C onnectors.java:168) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpSe rverExchange.java:687) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker( Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_11]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_11]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_11]
```

---

### **here is the security-bean.xml file**

```
<http use-expressions="true">

<intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll"/>
<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>

<form-login/>

</http>

<authentication-manager>
<authentication-provider ref="ldapActiveDirectoryAuthProvider"/> 
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="ldapActiveDirectoryAuthProvider"
class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentic ation.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider ">
<beans:constructor-arg value="example.com"/>
<beans:constructor-arg value="ldap://192.XXX.XX.XXX:389/"/>
<beans:property name="useAuthenticationRequestCredentials" value="true" />
<beans:property name="convertSubErrorCodesToExceptions" value="true" />
</beans:bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the Apache commons-lang version that is getting picked up at runtime is not the same as the one being used at compile time. This can happen for many reason but the most common ones are:

1. You have two versions of commons-lang in your server classpath.
2. There is only one version of commons-lang in your server classpath but it's an older one that doesn't include the following method:

   StringUtils.replaceEach

Hope this helps.